# JNI UnsatisfiedLink Error

Tags: java, c, netbeans, java-native-interface, native-methods

So I'm new to JNI and I'm following a simple hello word example but I keep getting error `UnsatisfiedLinkError`. What am I doing wrong? Here's my .h file:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class JNITEST_jnihellonative */

#ifndef _Included_JNITEST_jnihellonative
#define _Included_JNITEST_jnihellonative
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
* Class:     JNITEST_jnihellonative
* Method:    hellofromc
* Signature: ()V
*/
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JNITEST_jnihellonative_hellofromc(JNIEnv *,jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

.c File

```
#include <jni.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include "jnihellonative.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_JNITESTS_jnihellonative_hellofromc(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
    printf("Hello World");
    return;
  }
```

java main class

```
package JNITEST;


public class Jnihello {


   public static void main(String[] args) {
        jnihellonative jniprint = new jnihellonative();
        jniprint.hellofromc();
   }

}
```

java class

```
package JNITEST;


public class jnihellonative {

    public native void hellofromc();

    static{
        System.load("C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JniHelloTest.dll");
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNITEST.jnihellonative.hellofromc()V
    at JNITEST.jnihellonative.hellofromc(Native Method)
    at JNITEST.Jnihello.main(Jnihello.java:19)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

I have tried using System.load() and System.loadLibrary() but i get same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've changed the name of your class since you generated the .h file and wrote the .c file. The .h file has `jnihellonative`, your Java code has `Jnihello`.

> I have tried using System.load() and System.loadLibrary()

Irrelevant. You're not getting the exception from either of these, you're getting it when calling your native method.

Comment: Thanks, I re-generated the .h and . c files and are identical from the ones i previously had but i did change the name of the files to JNITEST_jnihellonative and that seemed to work.

Comment: Not possible. Changing the names of .h or .c files doesn't have any effect on Java. You had to change the name of the native method from `Java_JNITESTS_jnihellonative_hellofromc` to `Java_JNITEST_JniHello_hellofromc`.

Comment: if i change to `Java_JNITEST_JniHello_hellofromc` the problem remains because it is `javahellonative` that has the jni native method. So what i did was clean and build java code, delete the old .h and .c files a generate new ones with the name mentioned before, compile de C code and generate a dll file and run the program. That seemed to work for me. Also when comparing the new .c and .h with the old ones theyre still the same.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The required name of the JNI native method *is* `Java_JNITEST_JniHello_hellofromc`. The statement 'it is javahellonative that has the jni native method' is meaningless.